# How to connect PBI to detect an open door

Tags: switches, button, reed-switch

What's the best way to connect a wired magnetic contact stripe [edit: a "reed switch"] to the door, in order to detect whether or not it's open.

I'm not interested in a wireless one, I'm building all the circuits from scratch, so I want a wired one.

The way I thought to do that is, to use a push button interface (in my case, a KNX PBI), and connect it to the a magnetic contact stripe on the door.

Here is an [example for a KNX PBI](http://www.gira.com/en/gebaeudetechnik/systeme/knx-eib_system/knx-produkte/tasterschnittstellen/knxeib-universal-tasterschnittstelle.html).

On the door the [magnetic contact stripe](https://www.adafruit.com/product/375) would close/open the circuit and notice the PBI when the door is closed/opened.

My question is, what's the best location to place the PBI? Should I place a switch near the door, and put the PBI behind it?

Should I pull the cables of the PBI far, to the fuse box?

(Migrated from home improvements SE site, as seems more relevant here.)

Comment: You should add a link to the KNX PBI. What is it? Also, I guess that English is not your first language. You should add your country into your user profile so we can make allowance for that.

Comment: Unless you want additional things connected to the PBI right there, you might as well just wire the reed switch back to the main control box, or somewhere you can fit one PBI to monitor multiple doors.

Comment: @Finbarr wouldn't I be limited by the distance? Would it be a good idea to have a long cable for the PBI at home?

Comment: @Transistor apologies for my English. I'll be glad if you'll let me know how can I improve my writing.

Comment: Your English is excellent. I think you did a literal translation to "stripe". We use "reed" as in a "reed of grass". (Those switches have long, thin metal contacts.) If we can see in your profile what country you are from then sometimes someone can give you a better translation.

Comment: No, intruder alarm systems have often used a number of reed switches connected in series on cables that run all over a house. Now that hardware has become cheaper they tend to have more inputs on the control units so that individual sensors can be identified. As long as the input impedance of the control input is low enough it's not a problem.

Comment: @Finbarr but is it a design to have these? Wouldn't the cabling be more expensive than connecting it to existing switch (which is already connected to the KNX bus). Also, how can I check in the PBI specs (see link inside) whether or not impedance would affect me, and how much distance would be OK.

Comment: @Transistor I can see Israel in my profile under location in public settings. Not sure why others can't see it. Anyhow a reed switch is just what I had in mind.

Comment: @Finbarr also, in alarm systems, are the control unit placed inside the fuse box? Inside the wall?

Comment: Can't speak for other countries but UK fuse boxes aren't large enough to have the alarm controls placed inside, and that would probably breach wiring regulations anyway. They tend to be placed somewhere out of the way but where it's easy to run cables to.

Comment: I see your country in the profile now. I must have missed it.

Comment: @Finbarr those PBI KNX inputs are supposed to be placed behind a regular pushbuton, and send a message to the KNX actuator so that it would switch on/off the light. Have a look at the data sheet, e.g., http://www.knx-gebaeudesysteme.de/sto_g/English/PRODUCT_MANUALS/USU_X2_PH_EN_V1-2_2CDC504019D0203.PDF